# In quantum circuits, why does $UNU^\dagger$ act on states in the same way $N$ acts before the operation?

Tags: quantum-circuit, gottesman-knill

I understand that the Schrodinger picture changes the quantum states, while the Heisenberg picture changes the operators. In this paper [The Heisenberg Representation of Quantum Computers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9807006.pdf), in equations 1,2, what does it mean that "*so after the operation, the operator $UNU^\dagger$ acts on states in just the way the operator $N$ did before the operation*"?

Comment: StackExchange sites are best suited for posts asking individual, laser-focused questions. I took the liberty of removing the second part of the post, as it was asking a seemingly separate question. Feel free to ask that one in a separate post

Comment: Thank you for the edits!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have some state $\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\lvert#1\rangle}\ket\psi$ (though note that you could make the identical argument using an arbitrary vector rather than a state), and you consider the action of some operator $N$ on it. Here, $N$ could be another gate, an operator representing some measurement, or just an arbitrary abstract operation that you are interested in for whatever reason. You thus get the state (or vector) $N\ket\psi$.

If you now ask how this state evolves through some gate $U$, you get $UN\ket\psi$. There is, however, a different (but equivalent) way of thinking about this: because $U$ is unitary, you can write $UNU^\dagger U\ket\psi$. This means that rather than thinking about $\ket\psi$ evolving through the two operations, you can interpret this as applying the operation $UNU^\dagger$ to the evolved vector $U\ket\psi$.

In some cases, this might make for an easier analysis of how states evolve through a circuit. Case in point, you might find that if $N\in\mathcal P$ for some group $\mathcal P$, then the map $N\mapsto UNU^\dagger$ is a group homomorphism, provided $U$ has specific properties (namely, in general, provided that $U$ belongs to the normaliser of $\mathcal P$ in the relevant group of unitaries).

If you then consider such "effective evolution" for sufficiently many $N$, you end up effectively offloading the task of calculating the evolution of $\ket\psi$ into that of calculating the evolution of a set of $N$, which might be easier if you can show that you need a relatively small number of operations $N$ to do this, and  that such set of operations is invariant under the action of some subgroup of unitaries.

Comment: Thanks! According to Nielsen&Chuang, section 10.5.2, it seems that $N$ is assumed to be a stabilizer of $|\psi>$ for this Heisenberg interpretation to work?

Comment: I'm not making any assumption on $N$ here. I'm not sure what you are referring to exactly without knowing what the text says

Comment: I guess I'm still confused about exactly what it means for operators $UNU^\dagger$ and $N$ to act on states in the same way. Before applying $U$, the operator $N$ takes $\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\lvert#1\rangle}\ket\psi$ to $N\ket{\psi}$. After applying $U$, the operator $UNU^\dagger$ takes the state $U\ket{\psi}$ to $UN\ket{\psi}$. How are these two behaviors considered the 'same'?

Comment: @FSeed those two do not act in the same on the state, that's not what is being said. It's $UN$ and $UNU^\dagger U$ which act in the same way